# 1st Order Nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that $y = −x^2$
is a solution for the equation $y' = x^3+
2y/x-y^2/x$.

Find the general solution for the equation. How would I go about solving this question?

Comment: Checking whether $y=-x$ is a solution of $y' = x^3 +  2y/x + y^2/x$ can be accomplished by substitution.  Do you know what the derivative $y'$ is when $y=-x$?  It's hard to guess what your background and interests are when you simply state "I have no idea".

Comment: No, I don't have a problem with showing that -x is a solution I just don't know how to find the general Solution.Thanks.

Comment: Well, it doesn't appear to me to be true that $y=-x$ is a solution.  Perhaps you have left out parentheses or made some other error in copying the problem?

Comment: An you are correct thanks it's -x^2

Comment: No, that's not a solution either. $y = i x^2$ would be a solution.

Comment: Maybe it should be $y' = x^3 + 2 y/x - y^2/x$?

Comment: I checked the original question again an it's correct. It may be the questions wording the guy who made the question doesn't know English so well.

Comment: The English isn't the problem, the mathematics is.

Comment: Ah I made a mistake , let me correct it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use "variation of parameters".  Since you know that $y= -x^2$ is a solution, look for a solution of the form $y= -x^2u(x)$ for some function u(x).  Then

1) $y'= -x^2u'- 2xu$.

2)$2y/x= -2x^2u/x= -2xu$

3)$-y^2/x= -x^4u^2/x= -x^3u$

so the equation becomes $-x^2u'- 2xu= x^3- 2xu- x^3u$ which reduces to $u'= x(u- 1)$.  That separates as $\frac{du}{u- 1}= xdx$.  Integrate on both sides to get $ln|u- 1|= \frac{1}{2}x^2+ C$.  Take the exponential of both sides: $u(x)- 1= C'e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2- x}$ where $C'= e^C$.  Therefore, the general solution to the differential equation is $y(x)= -x^2u(x)= C'x^2e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2- x}- x^2$.  Notice that you get the original given function by taking C'= 0,

Comment: It's an apt suggestion.  Future Readers may benefit from noting that you derived a linear ODE for the variation $u$, which is of course more routine to handle than the original nonlinear ODE.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$y'(x)=x^3+\frac{2y(x)}{x}-\frac{y(x)^2}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $y(x)=-xr(x)$ so $y'(x)=-r(x)-xr'(x)$:

---

$$-r(x)-xr'(x)=x^3-xr(x)^2-2r(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$r'(x)=r(x)^2+\frac{r(x)}{x}-x^2\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $r(x)=-\frac{q'(x)}{q(x)}$ so $r'(x)=\frac{q'(x)^2}{q(x)^2}-\frac{q''(x)}{q(x)}$:

---

$$\frac{q'(x)^2}{q(x)^2}-\frac{q''(x)}{q(x)}=\frac{q'(x)^2}{q(x)^2}-\frac{q'(x)}{xq(x)}-x^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-q''(x)=-\frac{q'(x)}{x}-x^2q(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$q''(x)-\frac{q'(x)}{x}-x^2q(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $t=\frac{ix^2}{2}\Longleftrightarrow x=(i-1)\sqrt{t}$:

---

$$q''(x)+\frac{\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)q'(x)}{\sqrt{t}}+2itq(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

By the chain rule:

---

$$2itq''(t)+2itq(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$q''(t)+q(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Assume a solution will be proportional to $e^{\mu t}$ for some constant $\mu$.

Substitute $q(t)=e^{\mu t}$:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\left(e^{\mu t}\right)+e^{\mu t}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\left(e^{\mu t}\right)=\mu^2 e^{\mu t}$:

---

$$\mu^2 e^{\mu t}+e^{\mu t}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{\mu t}\left(\mu^2+1\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Since $e^{\mu t}\ne0$ for a finite $\mu$, the zeros must come from the polynomial:

---

$$\mu^2+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mu=\pm i$$